# Hidden Markov Model for three-sided dice

Tags: algorithm, probability, bioinformatics, hidden-markov-models

I was taught HMM and given this homework problem. I understood a part of it, but I'm not sure if its correct. The problem is:

> Consider a different game where the dealer is not flipping a coin,
>   but instead rolling
>       a three-sided die with labels 1, 2, and 3. (Try not to think about what a three-sided
>       die might look like.) The dealer has two loaded dice D1 and D2. For each die Di, the
>       probability of rolling the number i is 1/2, and the probability of each of the other two
>       outcomes is 1/4. At each turn, the dealer must decide whether to (1) keep the same
>       die, (2) switch to the other die, or (3) end the game. He chooses (1) with probability
>       1/2 and each of the others with probability 1/4. At the beginning the dealer chooses
>       one of the two dice with equal probability.
>
> - Give an HMM for this situation. Specify the alphabet, the states, the transition
>     probabilities, and the emission probabilities. Include a start state start, and assume
>     that the HMM begins in state start with probability 1. Also include an end
>     state end.
> - Suppose that you observe the following sequence of die rolls: 1 1 2 1 2 2. Find a
>     sequence of states which best explains the sequence of rolls. What is the probability
>     of this sequence? Find the answer by completing the Viterbi table. Include
>     backtrack arrows in the cells so you can trace back the sequence of states. Some of
>     the following facts may be useful:
>
>   log2(0) = −∞
>     log2(1/4) = −2
>     log2(1/2) = −1
>     log2(1) = 0
> - There are actually two optimal sequences of states for this sequence of die rolls.
>     What is the other sequence of states?

If I'm not wrong for the first part I have to do something like here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model#A_concrete_example But I didn't get what is to assume start with probability 1.

Also, I'm not sure what I have to do for Viterbi table in the second part of the question. If any body can give me some hint or clue, that will be great.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Well, I don't think it's related to programming. I don't have to do any programming for this question just design HMM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To assume your starting probability is one:**
In HMM you either have a fixed starting-state or a probability-distribution over all states which states how likely it is to start in state X. To assume that your starting probability of a given state is 1 equals the first alternativ.

**Viterbi-algorithm:**
In the viterbi-matrix the ith row offten corresponds to the ith states and the jth column corresponds to the prefix of lenth j of your emitted symbol. In each entry (i,j) is the maximal probability to that you have seen prefix j already and your are in state i.

For your backtracking you need to keep track for every (i,j)-cell which maximal precursor was involved in the computation of the (i,j)-cell. If you have this information you can backtrack from the cell with the highest value in the last column to the beginning. Reverse this backtrack and you got your viterbi-path.

Comment: So will it something like: there is a start state that starts with probability 1, then further the dealer choosing one of the 2 dice is 1/2 (as given in question: At the beginning the dealer chooses one of the two dice with equal probability.)

Comment: Yeah. That is the reason I don't have much of the computer-science background and never really learned HMM, though I heard of it most of the times. But I am trying to get hands on computer-science concepts, its interesting. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am studying bioinformatics as well. Maybe well meet again. :D

Comment: Nice to hear that. Well, I have another doubt about this question. I am trying to fill Viterbi table as in http://bio5495.wustl.edu/HMMs/HMMNotes.pdf For this question I consider 3 states(D1,D2,end) or just 2 of them? B'cos there are 3 things the dealer can do(1 with P=1/2 and 2 and 3 with P of 1/4 each). If its 3 how do I start in first column for end state? Also what will be the emission for end state. I'm lost.

Comment: I dont find the question but its totally fine to sometimes start the matrix with 0s in some cells.